# Is it possible to mix split and single-supply circuit sections

Tags: circuit-design

I'm making an audio synthesizer which works with single supply. Now I'm interested to include a section that uses dual-supply (a filter using LM13600).

I'm thinking that it could be possible to do it, and I will scale and offset the dual supply part output so to add it in my single supply circuit chain. Can dual and single supplies be mixed in the same circuit? How should I connect the grounds together?

Comment: Usually the reason to have a single-supply audio circuit is to avoid the muss and fuss of making that negative supply.  If you're going to cross the Rubicon, you may as well do the whole thing dual supply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is, this is done all the time. The key is to make sure all supplies share the same ground. By sharing the the same ground the supplies current can find it's way back to the supply.

One note: If you are passing DC from one circuit to the next, it becomes important to watch for voltage ranges. A ±5 supply that connects to the input stage of another analog section that has rails of 0V to 5V it might violate the voltage range of the input (most inputs have diodes that turn on after Vcc or Vdd plus the diode voltage usually 0.3V). For example an output of -5V going to an input that can't go lower than -0.3V might source too much current. In this case attenuators or series resistors might need to be added.

In the case of capacitively connected audio, this would not be a problem.

Here is an example of single ended and dual supply mixed:

[image]

All the voltage rails are generated with LDO's or DC to DC converters and share the same ground.

Comment: For an audio system you would want to make sure to use a DC blocking cap between single-ended and dual-supply sections.

Comment: @TimWescott This is not an audio system, it serves as an example of mixed dual and single sided supplies

Comment: But the **OP** says: "I 'm making an audio synthesizer".  So I embellished your answer with something pertinent to audio.

Comment: @TimWescott I don't do audio so I don't have an example readily available to post

Comment: Can you tell me what will happen if the negative rail accidentally pass to the single-supply circuit? The single supply section V is 5.5V and the split-supply i'm planning to use is +12, -12.

Comment: It depends on the circuit and the op amp, if there is a cap, you don't need to worry about it